# Audio Streaming in windows phone app (no Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, audio-streaming

I am trying to play an audio stream from stream server in my windows phone app. I read on Microsoft Documentation that I have to reference an Audio Stream Agent.

I have these projects in my solution : 
[image]
I've tried to reference a new project as Audio Streaming Agent in my Windows Phone 8.1 application

[image]

but I keeping receiving the error :

[image]

I read that I have to change the target framework, but there is no option for target framework in the AudioStreamAgent1 properties.

Also, Can I do this using an application that is not the Silverlight kind? Is there a way to do without using the Silverlight one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `AudioSteamAgent` is targeted at WP Silverlight, and your actual app is WP8.1 (WinRT).

To create background audio in WP8.1, you will want to use the [Background Media Player.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx)

You can find a great guide for how to get started [here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/).

But basically (without all the boilerplate code to wire everything up), it comes down to telling the BMP what to play (code is from the link above):

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring02.wma"));
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
```

And telling the OS player controls what to show, and what to do when the user interacts with them:

```
systemmediatransportcontrol = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
systemmediatransportcontrol.ButtonPressed += systemmediatransportcontrol_ButtonPressed;
systemmediatransportcontrol.PropertyChanged += systemmediatransportcontrol_PropertyChanged;
systemmediatransportcontrol.IsEnabled = true;
systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPauseEnabled = true;
systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPlayEnabled = true;
systemmediatransportcontrol.IsNextEnabled = true;
systemmediatransportcontrol.IsPreviousEnabled = true;
```

This is all assuming that you want the user to be able to leave the app and have media continue to play. If you just want to stream audio/video while the user is in the app you can use the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) control.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in answering it. I will try this.  :)